# Time series clustering: Is shape-based distance robust to non-stationarity? If not, is differencing a valid solution?

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity, hierarchical-clustering

I'm working in R using the dtwclust package (Sarda-Espinosa 2018), and I want to cluster a set of time series hierarchically by the shape-based distance (SBD) metric (Paparizzos and Gravano 2015).

Is the SBD method robust to non-stationarity? If not, is differencing my raw data to achieve stationarity a valid pre-processing step for SBD clustering?

The same questions could be asked of the other distance metrics out there; SBD is just the one I've been exploring the most.